# whats is wrong with the php code?(mysql query)

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php 
   include"config.php";

   session_start();

   $kind = $_GET['kind'];

   $errormsg = '';

   if($kind == user)
    {  $tablename = "appusers"; }
    else
    { $tablename = "developers"; }

   if(isset($_POST['setemail'])){

   $setemail = $_POST['setemail'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$tablename' WHERE email = '$setemail'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
   {
       $errormsg = "good";
   }
   else
   {
       $errormsg = "not valid";
   }
   }            
?>
```

I get not valid all the time.
when I write the table name without variable it works...

Comment: use : `mysql_query ("SELECT ...") or die (mysql_error ())` It will give you some information if you got a problem. Are you sure if there is a row in your DB with the email value exaclty like `$_POST['setemail']` ?
Last thing : don't forget to securise your POST variable :-)

Comment: `if($kind == user)` Is `user` defined as a constant?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE email = '$setemail'
```

`$tablename` doesn't need single quotes.

Also, you may do this:

```
if(mysql_errno()){
     echo mysql_error();
     exit;
}
```

After each query to see mysql errors.

Comment: and you could also protect yourself a little by `$setemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['setemail']);`

Comment: and http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: It'a pity to see such a wrong answer so much upvoted. Echoing mysql errors out is a breach in security, revealing a lot of sensiteve info to a potential attacker. Mysql error have to be translated into PHP error instead.

Comment: I think printing the mysql error here is just meant for debugging...

Comment: **Yes**, it is. Also it helps with this type of errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to escape your table name, use `$tablename` instead of '$tablename'

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
 $tablename = "developers";
    $errormsg = '';

    if(!empty($_GET['kind']) && $_GET['kind'] == "user") 
    { 
        $tablename = "appusers"; 
    } 


   if(isset($_POST['setemail'])){

   $setemail = $_POST['setemail'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE email = '$setemail'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
     {
     $errormsg = "good";
      }
        else
        {
          $errormsg = "not valid";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backquotes for table names, not single quotes

Also, you should try to get more error information from your query.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$tablename` WHERE email = '$setemail'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    $errormsg = "good";
}
else
{
    if ($sql)
        $errormsg = "not valid";
    else
        $errormsg = mysql_error();
}
```